# How to determine type of variable that's set to null?

Tags: javascript, typescript

In Javascript, if a variable `foo` is set to null, then `typeof(foo)` will be `object`.

In Typescript, it appears that even if `foo` was declared as a `number`, if `foo=null` then `typeof(foo)` will be `object` rather than `number`.

In Typescript/Javascript, is there any way to determine whether a variable is a `number` type, regardless of the fact that it might be temporarily set to `null`?

Comment: `temporarily` implies asynchronous code somewhere.

Comment: @JackBashford it may mean that the variable is declared but not used yet.

Comment: If your code is like: `let num: Number; num = null`, this should give you error. That is the whole point of Typescript, to avoid incorrect values set to variables.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to tell if a variable which is currently null will eventually be a number or not during runtime. JS is a dynamic type language. The variables could be of any type at any time during runtime. With Typescript you can at least tell at compile time what a variable type should be though.

You could try parseInt or parseFloat as an alternative though:

```
parseFloat(null)
// NaN

parseFloat(3)
// 3
```

Comment: Thank you, to clarify your statement @Talha, with TypeScript, how can I tell at compile time what a variable type is? Assume: `let foo : number = null;`, then `typeof(foo)` will return `object`. How can I check programmatically if `foo` was declared as a `number`?

Comment: Ah with TS if you were to try to use `foo` which was declared as a number in a parameter which is defined as a string let's say, the compiler will complain and not even compile. You don't check for it yourself, the compiler will type check for you. If you want to check programmatically you can try using  `parseInt` or `parseFloat` and seeing if the result is not `NaN`: `isNaN(parseInt(null))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var foo = null;
if(foo === null) {
    console.log('This is null var');
}
```

Comment: `typeof null -> 'object'`

Comment: @Rajesh What is the meaning of that?

Comment: `typeof null` will return `"object"`. not `null`

Answer (score 0):

basically, The `null` value is technically a `primitive(most basic data types of javascript)`, the way "object" or "number" are primitives.

```js
var foo = null;
if ( foo == null ){
  console.log('null');
}
```

Comment: It will fail this check `var foo; 

if (foo == null) console.log('null'); // => 'null'`

Comment: @flppv but that's not a requirement - the OP only wants to check `null`.